# Regex: Matching only groups that have a specific word embedded

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I cannot figure out how to match only on groups that contain a certain word ('**test**' for example below). It is a big text file and the groups start with a line '**Group** x' and include text with an empty line separation to the next group. I think I need to use lookaheads and lookbehinds but don't know how. I can use vb.net for this but trying to test out different expressions in the regex testers and can't get anywhere.

```
Group 1
adfdf
dd   test  ddfdf
dfdfadf

Group 2
ddfadfa

Group 3
add  test 
adfdff

Group 4
adfdf
```

Expected 2 matches:

```
Group 1
adfdf
dd   test  ddfdf
dfdfadf

Group 3
add  test 
adfdff
```

Comment: Not sure how to reword the question. I was specific in how the text file looks and what matches I expected. I got an answer below that works. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your pattern with `^Group \d+$` and end with `(?:^$|\Z)`. In the middle match `test` but not preceeded by an empty line `$(?:.(?!^$)` (see [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for details on how the latter works). Don't forget the `m` and `s` modifiers:

```
^Group \d+$(?:.(?!^$))*?test.*?(?:^$|\Z)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kM9qB3/2

Comment: You're a genius! This works and I need to study this on how it works. I thought I needed some kind of lookarounds for this. I checked the web and couldn't find anything related to this puzzle. Maybe someone asked before, not sure. I am still learning regex and there seems to be different solution to the same puzzle. I am not sure if there are any others but it works. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed that if the word test is in the last Group section, then it doesn't match on it. It matches all the other groups correctly.

Comment: Update the answer to fix the last group issue. The closing pattern should be "either empty line or end of the whole text" - `(?:^$|\Z)`

Comment: In fact it contains a lookaround, namely negative lookahead, as a part of more complex "no empty line after newline but and before 'test'" - `$(?:.(?!^$))`. It is explained in details in the question I referred to in my post.

Comment: Cool thanks. Yes I have been looking at this and saw the lookaround after I wrote. It is going to take me awhile to figure out this regex stuff.